# Restrict upload of file types for Plone authors

Tags: security, tinymce, plone, zope

Is there a way to restrict the upload of certain filetypes by Plone authors eg an upload filter banning say *.exe etc?

Also is it possible to add a TinyMCE restriction like this: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/MCImageManager:upload.extensions

Would be good if this was in the TinyMCE control panel.

Comment: Are using Dexterity? Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145087/restrict-upload-by-filetype-or-mimetype-using-dexterity-on-plone/14145574#14145574

Comment: Here is an example of server-side-validation for audio-files, that might give you inspiration how to validate  other file-types, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264737/django-python-how-to-read-a-file-and-validate-that-it-is-an-audio-file

Comment: See also Mozilla's excellent doc about W3C's file-API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications