# Using the Blazor InputFile tag- how can I control the file type shown when I browse

Tags: .net, blazor

Can I control the file type filter shown when I click the button to browse a directory and select file(s)?

I want to select only *.xml files for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can limit the file type  by adding the accept attribute

```
<InputFile OnChange="OnFileChange" accept=".xml" />
```

more information here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/accept

Answer (score 4):

You can use [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21565344/842935)  attribute:

```html
<InputFile OnChange="@OnInputFileChange" multiple accept=".xml,.xsdl"/>
```

I write two extensions (`.xml,.xsdl`) to people who needs more than one file type.